# Currency field is behaving very differently

Tags: currencytype

I have a `Currency(17, 1)` field "Revenue" on a custom object. here i have defined only one digit after decimal point but in few records it is storing more than 1 digit after decimal point.

```
like - 118089.67995513866
```

I am not getting any clue why is this behaving like this.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: How are you populating this field's value?

Comment: Is this occurring on standard detail page or visualforce page ?

Comment: yes i am binding this using <Apex:inputText> tag. I am using visualforce page.

Comment: You should use Apex:inputField for a field, this will display with the precision that you have defined.

Comment: i have tried <apex:inputField> tag as well but result is same

Comment: Sorry - if you are wanting to view then you should use apex:outputField. Use apex:inputField for edit / creation

Comment: Actually on view page we are providing an option to change the value of this field thats why i used inputText

Comment: Use inputField instead of inputText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is how it is displayed in an input or outputfield, or on a standard page layout.

As you have noticed, the actual value is stored with greater precision. The user can't enter it to this precision, but it could be for example dataloaded or calculated by apex code. This isn't normally an issue, since the display the user sees is at the precision specified. And it allows calculations to be carried out more accurately. What particular problem is it causing you?

You can use the decimal setScale methods if you are working with it in Apex and require this.

EDIT

The issue here is because you are using an apex:inputfield for display. If I have a currency field defined as Precision (17,1) and I input a value with more decimal places e.g. 1.23456 in the inputfield, then the truncation is applied when I save the record and the value 1.2 would be stored in the database.
You should be able to try this on your own page by entering a lot of numbers after the decimal point and then save / refresh.

If a value with greater precision exists in the database (which can happen through code, or through dataloading), then this information is not truncated. The apex:outputfield applies the mask (so you would only see 1 decimal place) but the apex:inputfield does not.

If you can't use apex:outputfield on your view page, then you may need to address how the data got into the system in the first place. Look at who created the records and when, to help track this down.

Comment: It is displaying 118089.67995513866 value on view page but i want to display only single digit after decimal point on view page.

Comment: Use an apex:outputfield to display this on your view page

Comment: i can't actually on view page user can edit this value and save again

Comment: If i enter "118089.67995513866" value in to text box and click on save then value "118089.67995513866" is being stored into database. It is not doing any rounding

Comment: That's very strange as I have just done an experiment myself using apex:inputField and it did truncate it properly in the value stored to the database. Can you post your VF page source? And any controller if applicable?

Comment: Actually i am doing javascript manipulations on this field thats why it is not doing any truncate i think

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link for your queries :

techblog.appirio.com/2012/11/salesforce-and-decimal-places.html